# Apple TV remote play pause doesn’t work

Tags: appletv

I never updated the beta and my play pause button does not work whatsoever, I am hesitant to download any updates anymore because my once well working remote now doesn’t have a play pause button and I usually switch to my Roku or firestick because my Apple product won’t pause or play. I can press mouse pad to pause but what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: If you are using a beta then you need to report the bug to Apple, so hopefully they can fix it in the next beta.

Comment: Did you try recharging the remote to see if the battery is just low?

Comment: The remote is at 100%, I never downloaded the beta update because you had to do that through a PC and my Mac Mini is obsolete now because it’s 11 years old and it won’t update anymore rendering it useless. A frustrating pattern Apple has. Equipment that becomes unusable so you have to upgrade to newer equipment, I don’t have the kind of money to stay afloat in an Apple ecosystem. Maybe I can sell the remote and the appletv4k 64GB.